# NtQueryInformationProcess ProcessConsoleHostProcess returns wrong Process ID

Tags: c, windows, 64-bit, windows-nt

I am using `NtQueryInformationProcess` : `ProcessConsoleHostProcess` to query the process ID of the conhost.exe process that is associated with a console application in Windows 10 x64. The function returns a success status code, but I always get an **odd number**, which is always one more than the actual PID. See the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8435.png). My code is complied for x64.

Is there anything wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory, process ids are a multiple of 4.  It wouldn't surprise me that the low two bits are being borrowed for some reason.

Comment: Oh, so is it safe to clip it to a multiple of 4, I mean something like testtest = testtest & ~(sizeof(int) - 1);

Comment: Yes, process IDs are assigned out of a handle table, so, just like with kernel handles, the least significant two bits of a PID are available for internal use. You can clear these two bits with `testtest &= ~3`, but it's not necessary if you're only passing the value to `OpenProcess`.

Comment: Thanks, I see. It is necessary in my case, I need to record processIds.